# Using Typescript, Webpack 4 and React each time I include a scss file the style name is undefined in className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I am building a React App using Typescript and Webpack 4.  I am trying to include class names from an scss file in my components, but when I do this the class name is undefined.

The big problem I'm having is that a lot of tutorials and pages online recommend using ExtractTextPlugin but this isn't compatible with webpack 4.  That's why I have to use the MiniCssExtractPlugin and the typings-for-css-modules-loader.

The following are my dependencies in my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm-check": "^5.8.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.18.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "little-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
}
```

My webpack.config.js includes the following under module => rules along with the other stuff for handling my typescript files etc.

```
{
    test: /\.(s*)css$/,
    use: [
        "style-loader",
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options:
            {
                publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
            options:
            {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                namedExport: true,
                camelCase: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]_[local][hash:base64:5]',
                banner: "// *** Generated File - Do not Edit ***"
            }
        },
        {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options:
            {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an scss file called map.styles.scss which only contains the following

```
.map-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

When the webpack build runs it generates the following file called map.styles.scss.d.ts

```
// *** Generated File - Do not Edit ***
export const mapContainer: string;
```

I am able to reference the file in my typescript now with the appropriate reference to the className as follows

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as styles from './map.styles.scss';

export class Map extends React.Component {

    render() {        
        return (                    
            <div ref='map' className={styles.mapContainer}>         
                Loading map...                    
            </div>                  
        );        
    }
}
```

The problem is that whilst the styles is an object, mapContainer is undefined.  As a result when my app is built, the className isn't present because there is no value to apply and so the style doesn't work.

I'm finding it strange that I can reference the styles but I don't get the string which represents the class.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

The issue was using both MiniCssExtractPlugin and style-loader.  This generated two files which the styles object tried to reference.

One generated a dictionary of keys which matched the styles.mapContainer reference to a value and one contained a load of javascript which I'm not 100% clear on what it did.

I needed the one with the dictionary of values.  By taking out the styles-loader I was left with the dictionary file and not the other one and then because there was no ambiguity it picked up the localised class names.

The following is my final webpack config for generating the css.

```
{
    test: /\.(s*)css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options:
            {
                publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
            options:
            {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                namedExport: true,
                camelCase: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]_[local][hash:base64:5]',
                banner: "// *** Generated File - Do not Edit ***"
            }
        },
        {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options:
            {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since you found the solution, please accept this answer as the correct one to mark the question as solved.